# Can I make array of structure public?

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

Can I make array of structures public, so that I can make function in other .asm file access it and modify it.

```
.data

NODE STRUCT
key dword ?
value dword ?
ends

THREE 10 DUP (0,0) NODE
```

And in the other .asm file to have a function that will access the array (THREE[0].KEY) and modify it.

I have tried but I reached a wall with the other function not knowing what NODE is. And I can't seem to find how to make NODE typedef STRUCT.

Comment: http://www.oopweb.com/Assembly/Documents/ArtOfAssembly/Volume/Chapter_8/CH08-10.html#HEADING10-41

Comment: in particular the `public` and  `extern` directives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the PUBLIC directive to make the symbol THREE accessible from other .ASM files. You also need to define THREE correctly:

```
    .data

NODE STRUCT
    key dword ?
    value dword ?
NODE ENDS

    PUBLIC THREE
THREE NODE 10 DUP ({0,0})
```

To access the symbol THREE you need to use the EXTERN directive:

```
NODE STRUCT
    key dword ?
    value dword ?
NODE ENDS

    EXTERN THREE:NODE

    .code
    mov THREE[0].KEY, 1
```

Note that this requires repeating the NODE struct definition twice, once in each .ASM file. To avoid this you can move it to separate file and include it both .ASM files. For example you can put the following in file named `node.inc`:

```
NODE    STRUCT
    key dword ?
    value   dword ?
NODE    ENDS
```

and include it a modified version of my second example above like this:

```
    INCLUDE node.inc

    EXTERN THREE:NODE

    .code
    mov THREE[0].KEY, 1
```

Comment: Even with EXTENRNDEF in my .inc file I still get linking error from both main and function asm file. Main has unresolved function, and function has unresolved THREE value.

I'm trying to create a function that recives data from stack, and in main im calling it after pushing with call. And in function asm I deffined it as a GetVal proc .. GetVal endp. Is my mistake somewhere in there?

Comment: It sounds like you're linking the files separately instead of together. Probably want you to do is something like `ml main.asm function.asm`.

Comment: I think you are right. But in my materials or online I cant find how to link files as in c. Can you point me to how to search for linking files in masm32? Or how to build makeit.bat file? English is not my native language so maybe that is why I'm missing it.

Comment: If something like `ml main.asm function.asm` doesn't work, you should post another question giving more details about what commands you're running and what error messages you're getting.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand where to enter that code.

Comment: On the command line or maybe in your `makeit.bat` file. Replace `main.asm` and `function.asm` with the names of the actual assembly files.